# Applying custom colors to bar charts in Cognos11

Tags: cognos, cognos-10, cognos-bi, cognos-8, cognos-11

I have a requirement to show a stacked and clustered bar chart in specific color given by the users in Cognos11 report studio. I have tried using the color palette options given in the chart properties but not able to apply my preferred color. Is there any way to achieve this in Cognos 11 Report Studio?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will work but:
In conditional formatting in Cognos you can use the RGB range to specify a precise colour.
You can also use hexadecimal colours - obviously that is a bit more complicated, and so you probably wouldn't, but if RGB doesn't work on a bar chart, maybe hexadecimal would
You can use Excel's DectoHex formula to convert an RGB colour to hexadecimal if you need to